# bingo con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio de un bingo en JavaScript para clases. Estoy intentando generar los cartones/tablas del juego pero como verán cuando se generan los números en la columna de una tabla estos se borran una vez son generados.

El programa funciona de la siguiente manera al pulsar el boton Enviar deberia de generar una tabla con numeros organizados por columnas y de menor a mayor.

Recomendaria usar debugger en las linea 125, en el metodo mostrarNumeros para ver el problema.

El resto del codigo parace funcionar el unico problema es que no sé porque se borra lo que he editado de html con jquery al recargar un bucle for.

```js
var rango = [];
/**
 * Genera la parte visual del carton del bingo. Una tabla de 3x9.
 */
function generarTabla() {
  var number_of_rows = 3;
  var number_of_cols = 9;
  var table_body = '<table border="1">';
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++) {
    table_body += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < number_of_cols; j++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          table_body +=
            '<td id="celda' +
            i +
            "-" +
            j +
            '" class="text-center text-white bg-primary">';
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        } else {
          table_body +=
            "<td id='celda" + i + "-" + j + "' class='text-center'>";
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        }
      } else {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          table_body +=
            "<td id='celda" + i + "-" + j + "' class='text-center'>";
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        } else {
          table_body +=
            '<td id="celda' +
            i +
            "-" +
            j +
            '" class="text-center text-white bg-primary">';
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        }
      }
    }
    table_body += "</tr>";
  }
  table_body += "</table>";
  $("#tablaDiv").html(table_body);
}

/**
 * @param num1 Rango minimo
 * @param num2 Rango maximo
 * @returns Array con todos los numeros entre el rango minimo y el rango maximo
 */
function generarRangos(num1, num2) {
  let min = Math.min(num1, num2);
  let max = Math.max(num1, num2);
  var output = Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (v, i) => i + min);
  if (num1 > num2) output.reverse();
  return output;
}

/**
 * @param columna Numero de la columna de la tabla
 * @returns Array con 3 numeros para colocar en las filas de la columna elegida
 */
function generarNumero(columna) {
  generarTabla();

  var numeros=[];
  var rango=[];
  switch (columna) {
    case 0:
     rango=generarRangos(1,9);  
    break;
    case 1:
     rango=generarRangos(10,19);
      break;
    case 2:
     rango=generarRangos(20,29);
      break;
    case 3:
     rango=generarRangos(30,39);
      break;
    case 4:
     rango=generarRangos(40,49);
      break;
    case 5:
     rango=generarRangos(50,59);
      break;
    case 6:
     rango=generarRangos(60,69);
      break;
    case 7:
     rango=generarRangos(70,79);
      break;
    case 8:
     rango=generarRangos(80,90);
      break;
  }

  //Bucle que cojera 3 numeros aleatorios diferentes
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var temp=rango[Math.floor(Math.random()*rango.length)];
    numeros.push(temp);
    var index=rango.indexOf(temp);
    rango.splice(index,1);
  }

  //Se ordena de minimo a maximo
  numeros.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
  return numeros;
}

//Sucede un problema de que el texto del resto de la tabla desaparece al terminar el array
/**
 * Funcion que muestra los numeros en la tabla tomados de la funcion generarNumero()
 */
function mostrarNumeros(){
  for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
    let numeros=generarNumero(index);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      $('#celda'+i+'-'+index).text(numeros[i]);
      /* document.querySelector('#celda'+i+"-"+j).innerHTML+=(numeros[i]) */
    }
  }
}

//Inicializa las funciones onClick
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#boton").click(mostrarNumeros);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
      table{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row border my-5">
        <div class="col-4 border">
          <form class="my-5">
            <div class="my-3">
              <label class="form-label">Numero de jugadores</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="number"
                name="players"
                id="players"
                max="20"
                min="5"
                value="5"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
              <label class="form-label">Valor del cartón</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="number"
                name="vcarton"
                id="vcarton"
                min="1"
                max="5"
                value="1"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
              <input
                class="btn btn-primary"
                type="button"
                name="boton"
                id="boton"
                value="Enviar"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDiv" class="col-8 border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Estas generando la tabla varias veces mientras se están generando los números, y los id se van sobreescribiendo hasta la última pasada.

Quita `generarTabla();` de aquí:

```
function generarNumero(columna) {
  generarTabla();
```

Y ponlo aquí:

```
function mostrarNumeros(){
  generarTabla();
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var rango = [];
/**
 * Genera la parte visual del carton del bingo. Una tabla de 3x9.
 */
function generarTabla() {
  var number_of_rows = 3;
  var number_of_cols = 9;
  var table_body = '<table border="1">';
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++) {
    table_body += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < number_of_cols; j++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          table_body +=
            '<td id="celda' +
            i +
            "-" +
            j +
            '" class="text-center text-white bg-primary">';
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        } else {
          table_body +=
            "<td id='celda" + i + "-" + j + "' class='text-center'>";
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        }
      } else {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          table_body +=
            "<td id='celda" + i + "-" + j + "' class='text-center'>";
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        } else {
          table_body +=
            '<td id="celda' +
            i +
            "-" +
            j +
            '" class="text-center text-white bg-primary">';
          table_body += "";
          table_body += "</td>";
        }
      }
    }
    table_body += "</tr>";
  }
  table_body += "</table>";
  $("#tablaDiv").html(table_body);
}

/**
 * @param num1 Rango minimo
 * @param num2 Rango maximo
 * @returns Array con todos los numeros entre el rango minimo y el rango maximo
 */
function generarRangos(num1, num2) {
  let min = Math.min(num1, num2);
  let max = Math.max(num1, num2);
  var output = Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (v, i) => i + min);
  if (num1 > num2) output.reverse();
  return output;
}

/**
 * @param columna Numero de la columna de la tabla
 * @returns Array con 3 numeros para colocar en las filas de la columna elegida
 */
function generarNumero(columna) {

  var numeros=[];
  var rango=[];
  switch (columna) {
    case 0:
     rango=generarRangos(1,9);  
    break;
    case 1:
     rango=generarRangos(10,19);
      break;
    case 2:
     rango=generarRangos(20,29);
      break;
    case 3:
     rango=generarRangos(30,39);
      break;
    case 4:
     rango=generarRangos(40,49);
      break;
    case 5:
     rango=generarRangos(50,59);
      break;
    case 6:
     rango=generarRangos(60,69);
      break;
    case 7:
     rango=generarRangos(70,79);
      break;
    case 8:
     rango=generarRangos(80,90);
      break;
  }

  //Bucle que cojera 3 numeros aleatorios diferentes
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var temp=rango[Math.floor(Math.random()*rango.length)];
    numeros.push(temp);
    var index=rango.indexOf(temp);
    rango.splice(index,1);
  }

  //Se ordena de minimo a maximo
  numeros.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
  return numeros;
}

//Sucede un problema de que el texto del resto de la tabla desaparece al terminar el array
/**
 * Funcion que muestra los numeros en la tabla tomados de la funcion generarNumero()
 */
function mostrarNumeros(){
  generarTabla();
  for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
    let numeros=generarNumero(index);
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      $('#celda'+i+'-'+index).text(numeros[i]);
      /* document.querySelector('#celda'+i+"-"+j).innerHTML+=(numeros[i]) */
    }
  }
}

//Inicializa las funciones onClick
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#boton").click(mostrarNumeros);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
      table{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row border my-5">
        <div class="col-4 border">
          <form class="my-5">
            <div class="my-3">
              <label class="form-label">Numero de jugadores</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="number"
                name="players"
                id="players"
                max="20"
                min="5"
                value="5"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
              <label class="form-label">Valor del cartón</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="number"
                name="vcarton"
                id="vcarton"
                min="1"
                max="5"
                value="1"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
              <input
                class="btn btn-primary"
                type="button"
                name="boton"
                id="boton"
                value="Enviar"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDiv" class="col-8 border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```